# What is the Apache equivalent of Nginx set_real_ip_from and real_ip_header for proxy protocol?

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, proxy

Nginx has `set_real_ip_from` and `real_ip_header proxy_protocol` directive to restrict the trusted IP address of the TCP load balancer.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/using-proxy-protocol/

But Apache only have `RemoteIPTrustedProxy`, which only works on the traditional X-Forwarded-For header.

What is the Apache equivalent of Nginx set_real_ip_from, real_ip_header for proxy protocol?

Answer (score 0):

RemoteIPHeader X-Forwarded-For
RemoteIPInternalProxy 10.0.0.0/8

reference: https://support.plesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025828373-Incorrect-IP-addresses-are-logged-by-Plesk-behind-a-load-balancer-or-reverse-forward-proxy